# chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy is undefined even though I added the low_energy flag

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-chrome-app, web-bluetooth

I am trying to write a chrome app that connects to a Bluetooth Low Energy device. I added `"bluetooth": { "low_energy": true }` to my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "DE1",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "128": "de1icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [],
  "bluetooth": {
    "uuids": ["A000"],
    "low_energy": true
  },
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["chrome.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

but when I call

```
chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy.connect
```

I get the error

> ```
> Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
> ```

The docs say this is what I should have been doing

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/bluetooth#reference

Answer (score 0):

I filed this as a bug at the chromium project

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=980766

and they have answered. Apparently this feature is only supported on ChromeOS and I am running macOS.